# How do I fetch host and pass from file in linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell

```
#!/bin/bash
hosts=(sarv savana simra punit)
pass=(sarva 1save xvyw23 asdwe87)

for i in "${!hosts[@]}"; do
    sshpass -p "${pass[i]}" ssh-copy-id -f root@"${hostnames[i]}" -p 22
done
```

Is it possible to fetch the password and hostname from a different file which consists of all hosts and their corresponding passwords in the following format:

```
host pass
sarv sarva
savana 1save
simra xvyw23
punit asdwe87
```

I apologize for not describing it properly.
The first word of each line in the file is the host-name and the second word is it's password.

Instead of writing hosts=(sarv savana simra punit) pass=(sarva 1save xvyw23 asdwe87) in the script.

Comment: sarv savana
savana 1save
simra xvyw23
punit asdwe87 first word of each line is the host and the second word is it's corresponding pass.

Comment: The reason why I put a password with spaces in your question was to make sure that you don't create a program that will break if a password with spaces is used (which is a common mistake).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading them from a file which combines both host and password could be done like this:

```
while IFS=' ' read -r host pass
do
    # your command using them goes here:
    echo "$host=$pass"
done < hostpass-list.txt
```

`IFS=' '` sets the input field separator to a space. The first space delimited word will be put in `host` and the rest of the line will be put in `pass`.

---

You may want to read all hosts/passwords first and use them later. In that case you could use an associative array.

```
# declare an associative array
declare -A hp

# fill the array
while IFS=' ' read -r host pass
do
    hp["$host"]="$pass"
done < hostpass-list.txt

# use the array
for host in "${!hp[@]}"
do
    pass="${hp["$host"]}"
    # your command using them goes here:
    echo "$host=$pass"
done
```

---

For reading from separate files (if that becomes necessary) I suggest using `readarray`:

```
readarray -t hosts < hosts-list.txt
readarray -t pass < passwords-list.txt
```

The `-t` means:

- Remove a trailing delim (default newline) from each line read.

Comment: Thank you for helping me Ted, but is it possible to fetch both hosts and their passwords from the same file.

Comment: @Shiva You're welcome. I didn't see the format of the combined file (before I edited the question) but I've now updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Of course:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

hosts=$(cat hosts-list.txt)
pass=$(cat passwords-list.txt)

for i in "${!hosts[@]}"; do
    sshpass -p "${pass[i]}" ssh-copy-id -f root@"${hostnames[i]}" -p 22
done
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me Antonio, but is it possible to fetch both hosts and their passwords from the same file.

Comment: Try this with passwords with spaces. It won't work.